# Class Diagram - Inheritance Relationship

Tags: class-diagram

If in class diagram I have a parent "Account" and three childs "Child1", "Child2", and "Admin". The "Admin" has control over "Child1" and "Child2" accounts. Will the relation be like this?

[image]

Comment: I'll let others answer whether the diagram encapsulates what you are asking. My worry here is your design. You are using inheritance, then you are tightly coupling `Admin` to other classes. Lastly, you have a design where an admin can edit a child1 or child2, but not another admin, which sounds like a bug already. Just replace all of this with a `allowedToEditOtherAccounts` flag in `Account` and move on. Job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram is is close to what you said.  But, just going by the names, `Child1` and `Child2` should not be classes. Those names are instances of `Child`.

Also, according to the [zero one infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) rule, in a design, there is no such thing as 2.  Everything is either zero, one, or some arbitrary user configurable number.  That's what the * you used is. A design with a 2 in it should raise your eyebrows.

Comment: Many thanks. I see your point. Actually the real diagram doesn't contain Child1 and Child2, it contains two different classes, maybe I had to specify that.